# open a new window using body onload

Tags: javascript

Edit- here's the code

```
<html> 
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var prodURL = "https://blah"; 

function postwith (to, params) { 
var myForm = document.createElement("form"); 
myForm.method = "post"; 
myForm.target = "_self"; 
myForm.action = to; 

for (var p in params) { 
var myInput = document.createElement("input"); 
myInput.setAttribute("name", p); 
myInput.setAttribute("value", params[p]); 
myInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
myForm.appendChild(myInput); 
} 

document.body.appendChild(myForm); 
myForm.submit(); 

} 
</script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
#overlayPageLoad { 
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white; 
height: 100% !important; 
left: 0; 
position: absolute; 
text-align: center; 
top: 0; 
width: 100% !important; 
} 
#overlayPageLoad .middle { 
color: #888888; 
font-size: 16px; 
left: 0; 
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
width: 100%; 
} 
</style> 

</head> 

<body onload= "postwith(prodURL, {SF_SESSION:'{!$Api.Session_ID}',SF_ENDPOINT:'{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_120}'})"; > 

<div id="overlayPageLoad"> 
<span class="middle"> 
<img src="https://prettypicture"> 
&nbsp;Connecting... 
</span> 
</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What does the function postwith, is it written by you or?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a pop-up, are you being evil?

Comment: the code wasn't written by me, and i don't do front end stuff. ever. business currently has the link open in the existing window, and now they want it in another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers only allow opening new windows in direct response to specific user-generated actions, like `click` events. You can't open them at other times (such as window load or unload), because it used to be that browsers allowed that, and it promptly got abused. So now we have popup-blockers.

**Update**: Re your comment:

> ...business currently has the link open in the existing window, and now they want it in another..

*That* you can do. You do it in the page linking to the page you want in a new window, not the page being opened, like this:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">text of link</a>
```

See the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target) of `a` elements.

Comment: i updated the code above to include the whole kitten kaboodle.

Comment: @nivyaj: ("Kit and kaboodle") First off, `form.target = "_self";` actively tells it to use the same window, you would want `form.target ="_blank";` to make it open a new one. But you can't do that reliably from an `onload` event handler, for the reason stated in my opening paragraph.

Comment: we don't have access to the reffering link. What we can do, is when the user clicks on that link, run an S-Control which gets us to where we want to go. The above code is the S-Control stuff.

Comment: @nivyaj: I don't know what an S-Control is, but I'm pretty sure you'll have to report back that browser pop-up blockers will not let you do this. If they had a button on the page saying "launch nifty thing" and the handler for **that** called `postwith`, that would be fine. But not `onload`.

Comment: so, it's working, i'm just losing all the login info, and we get a blank window....

Comment: @nivyaj: I find that surprising. Good luck with it,

Comment: well, we're using a CRM which is calling a web service. Not sure if there's some behind the scene stuff going on there... any advice on how to handle losing the credentials?